# Bulk update with condition in update query with SQLAlchemy ORM

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to do a bulk update where I have a condition in the update query. I have a list of IDs and I want to update **new_value** with the string in **old_value** if old_value if **not** None in the database. If the value of old_value is None, I want to use a 'default_value' string

I cant find any relevant info on how to do this. I think maybe a case stmt but I'm not sure how to format the query.

```
class MyTable(BaseModel):
    id = sa.Column(sa.String(256))
    new_value = sa.Column(sa.String(256))
    old_value = sa.Column(sa.String(256))
```

```
LIST_OF_IDS = [1,2,5,6]

update_query = db.session.query(MyTable).filter(MyTable.id.in_(LIST_OF_IDS)) \
     .update(dict(new_value=MyTable.old_value if MyTable.old_value else 'default_value'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create an `update` query using sqlalchemy `case` construct and then you can simply use `session.execute()`.

```
from sqlalchemy import update, case
update_query = (
    update(MyTable)
    .where(MyTable.id.in_(LIST_OF_IDS))
    .values(
        new_value=case(
            (MyTable.old_value.isnot(None), MyTable.old_value), else_="default_value"
    )
)
```

)